# KivyMD - Is there a way to change the size of an MDIcon within its container? i.e. Display a 50% scale MDIcon within one cell of a GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy, icons, scale, kivymd

I have a set of MDIcons laid out within a GridLayout but the icons are too large in appearance.  Is there a way to scale them to 50% of their size within the parent widget without altering the layout of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - sizing is altered in the same manner as text within MDLabel i.e. within KV language:

```
font_size: '15dp'
```

Comment: **Note:** `sp` should typically be used instead of `dp` as the unit for `font_size:` settings. To quote the [official documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html), "Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the `dp` unit, but it is also scaled by the user’s font size preference. We recommend you **use this unit when specifying font sizes,** so the font size will be adjusted to both the screen density and the user’s preference."

Answer (score 0):

```
icon_size:"50dp"
```

This is the correct way to change the size of **MDIconButton**